# Disappearing labels on large maps' edge - Easy Custom Labeling Plugin - QGIS 2.8.3

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I've been using the Easy Custom Labeling plugin to fine-tune placement of labels. However, I have been having some labels disappear when they are on the edge of large maps. For example, I have an A0 sized map where labels on the very right side disappear. Once I pan the map in the print composer towards the left, these labels appear little by little.

Anyone else experience this? Any way to fix it? For now, I am working around it by adding a second, smaller map on top of the area that has missing labels to sort of "mask" it.

[image]

Comment: Can you include an image? Is it just that there is not enough room on the right side of the map to place the labels?

Comment: @RichardLaw I will add an image when i get back to work. But to answer your question, there is more than enough room for the labels. I have a map as wide as an A0 and tall as an A4. The labels will disappear when the map content about 15 cm from each edge. They reappear when pushing the map content just a mm in the right direction.

Comment: @RichardLaw Do see updates with image.